# Обрезать строку до последней буквы

Tags: delphi

Как удалить строки до последней буквы в текстовом файле.

**Пример текстового файл (все буквы на английском):**

```
1Zadacha123=gotovo555
2Zadachawer=net543
3adacha123=est32
```

**На выходе получаем:**

```
555
543
32
```

**Как удалить до определенной буквы то понятно вот так:**

delete(s,1,pos('Буква',s));

Или

```
s:=copy(s,1,pos('Буква',s)-1);
```

Добавлен код:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Soap.EncdDecd, System.Hash, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, RegExpr, FileCtrl, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls,
  Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.IOUtils, System.DateUtils, StrUtils, System.Types,
  System.IniFiles, Vcl.ImgList,
  System.Math, Vcl.Samples.Spin, ShellApi, System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.ImageList;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  sl: TstringList;
  i: integer;
Begin
  sl := TstringList.Create();
  sl.loadFromFile('Загрузить.txt');
  for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do
  begin
    sl[i] := TRegExpr.replace(sl[i], '.*?(\d+)$', '$1');

  end;
  sl.SaveToFile('Сохранить.txt');
End;
```

И ошибку выдает в строке

```
sl[i] := TRegExpr.replace(sl[i], '.*?(\d+)$', '$1')
```

**при компиляции: Incompatible types:** 'Boolean' and 'string'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

данная задача не слишком то отличается от предыдущегов опроса, где вы вставляли `**test**` после последней буквы.

Загружаете текстовый файл целиком, например, с помощью `TStringList` и обрабатываете его построчно. Если файл очень большой то можно использовать другие средства и читать файл построчно, записывая результат в другой файл.

Далее проходитесь по строкам и, используя регулярные выражения, делаете одно следующих вариантов:

- замена всего что есть в строке, на этим самые цифры
- вытаскивание последних цифр и замена строки на нее целиком.

В первом случае имеем примерно такой код, используя `TRegEx.replace()`

```
sl := TStringList.create();
sl.loadFromFile('D:\qwe.txt');

for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do begin
     sl[i] := TRegEx.replace(sl[i], '.*?(\d+)$', '$1');   
    
end;

sl.saveToFile(...);
sl.free()
```

Во втором - используем `TRegEx.match()`

```
m := TRegEx.Match(sl[i], '.*?(\d+)$');
if (m.Success) then begin
    sl[i] := m.Groups[1].Value;
end;
```

Comment: При компиляции первого варианта таже ошибка что и была: Incompatible types: 'Boolean' and 'string' Именно в строке sl[i] := TRegExpr.replace(sl[i], '.*?(\d+)$', '$1'); то с этим делать не пойму.

Comment: @Татьяна если вы посмотрите [справку](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.RegularExpressions.TRegEx.Replace)
то заметите, что метод `replace` всегда возвращает `string`. Ошибка где-то в другом месте. Без вашего кода никто тут не угадает где именно.

Comment: добавьте к приведенному коду `program a; uses classes, system.regularexpressions; begin ... end.` и у вас будет полная консольная программа для проверки.

Comment: Добавила код в вопрос. Там где ошибка: Incompatible types: 'Boolean' and 'string'

Comment: @Татьяна я не знаю, по какой причине у вас класс называется `tregexprR` если везде он называется `tregex`. Подключения модуля `system.regularExpressions` я также не вижу. Правда виду модуль `regexpr`, но не знаю что это.

Comment: Все заработало! Разобралась! Неправильно подключала регулярные выражения. Спасибо Teran!

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
const
  numb = ['0' .. '9'];
var
   s: string;
   i: Integer;
begin
 s := '1Zadacha123=gotovo555';
 i := length(s);
 while i > 0 do
   if s[i] in numb then
      Dec(i)
   else
      Break;
 s := Copy(s, i + 1, length(s));
 Writeln(s);
```

Условие остановки подразумевает, что нужно извлечь последнюю группу цифр.